# В чем ошибка написания функции php для wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress

Необходимо было реализовать плагин для проверки занятости домена, плагин работает, но сейчас нужно добавить функционал как черный список доменов, написал функцию, но она не работает, в чем ошибка?

```
function black_list($domain_name)
{
    $black_l = 0;
    $mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'wordpress');
    $query = $mysqli->query('SELECT * FROM black_list');
    while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
        $black_l['id'] = $row['name'];
    }
    if ($black_l['id'] == $_POST['domain_name'])
        return -1;
    else
        return 0;
}

function check_domain( $domain_name ) {
    $host = htmlspecialchars( trim( $domain_name ) );
    $json = file_get_contents( 'http://ip-api.com/json/' . $host . '?lang=ru' );
    $array = json_decode( $json, true );
    if(black_list($domain_name) == 0) {
        if (strcasecmp($array['status'], 'fail') === 0) {
            return '<h5>Домен ' . $host . ' свободен</h5>';
        }
    }
else {
    return '<h5>Домен ' . $host . ' в черном списке</h5>';
}
    return '<h5>Домен ' . $host . ' зарегистрирован</h5>';
}
```

Comment: Что означает "не работает"?

Comment: В чём ошибка? В коде)

Comment: Я понимаю, но ошибок нет, а на странице сайта выводит #13 {main} thrown in D:\Programm_for_study\XAMPP\htdocs\Practic\wp-content\plugins\plug_domain\check_domain.php on line 18, как можно исправить?

Comment: и что же на этой линии находится?)

Comment: Находится ошибка, исправил....